# Run Process In Seperate Console Accross All Operating Systems

Tags: java, windows, command, cross-platform, exec

I need to run a program in it's own command window but I don't know how to do this across the major operating systems, I know in Windows I can use the start command but I don't know what the command equivalent of start is on other operating systems. The following code is what I have so far:

```
    switch(OS.THISOS){//OS has information about the current OS such as what OS it is and the locations of things like appdata, user home, and user working directory

    case OS.WINDOWS :
        cmd.add("/c");
        cmd.add("start");
        cmd.add("java");
        cmd.addAll(Arrays.asList(Init.getCommand()));//this gets the jvm arguments that this program needs
        new Exec().exec("cmd", cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]));//because start can not be directly executed through exec, I run cmd.exe and pass start in as an argument along with the command to run my program
        break;//Exec is a class that handles IO streams for the sub process

    case OS.MAC :
        //I believe open is the command for MAC but I don't know if it can be directly run with exec or if I need to do something similar to what I did for Windows, also if the later is the case how would I do that?
        break;

    case OS.LINUX :
        //I have seen several answers to this one but I don't know which command works best
        break;

    case OS.SOLARIS :
        //no idea what to do here
        break;

    default:
        System.err.println("OS not supported");//this should never happen since the program will crash in Init if the OS is unknown
        return;

    }
```

**Edit:**
I did some more research and came up with this, but I don't know if this will work:

```
switch(OS.THISOS){

    case OS.WINDOWS :
        cmd.add("/c");
        cmd.add("start");
        cmd.add("java");
        cmd.addAll(Arrays.asList(Init.getCommand()));
        new Exec().exec("cmd", cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]));
        break;

    case OS.MAC :
        cmd.add("-a");
        cmd.add("java");
        cmd.add("--args");
        cmd.addAll(Arrays.asList(Init.getCommand()));
        new Exec().exec("open", cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]));//will this work?
        break;

    case OS.UNKNOWN :
        System.err.println("OS not supported");
        break;

    default://at this point it's Linux, Solaris, or some other Unix system, xterm is the closest I can find to what I want
        cmd.add("-e");
        cmd.add("java");
        cmd.addAll(Arrays.asList(Init.getCommand()));
        new Exec().exe("xterm", cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]));
        return;

    }
```

If there is something wrong with how I have done this, please let me know how I can fix it.

Comment: What sort of program are you trying to run?

Comment: @Matthew Wilson it's a java program, 'Init.getCommand()' returns a string array containing the location of the jar and other arguments for the jvm

Comment: Just tested this on my mac, to open a terminal window and pass a command to it, I had to use this command:

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "java -version"'`

Replace java -version with the command to run your program